# Como compruebo si un metodo void se a realizado correctamente?

Tags: java

Me explico tengo un metodo void al que llamo en el main, la idea es que si el metodo se ejecuta correctamente salga un mensaje. Podria poner el metodo como String y sacar el mensaje en el pero me gusta mas que sea void. os dejo el metodo y el main.

```
 public void aniadirParte(int tipoParte, Parte p) {
    if (tipoParte == 1) {
        if (numParteM <= MAXPARTES) {
            this.listaDPartesM[numParteM] = (ParteMecanico) p;
        }
    }
    if (tipoParte == 2) {
        if (numParteP <= MAXPARTES) {
            this.listaDPartesP[numParteP] = (PartePintura) p;
        }
    }
    if (tipoParte == 3) {
        if (numParteR <= MAXPARTES) {
            this.listaDPArtesR[numParteR] = (ParteRevision) p;
        }
    }
}
```

Este es el metodo en el main

```
 case 1:
                int horas;
                int numMAteriales;
                String f;
                boolean finalizado;
                int parte;
                System.out.println("Introduzca el numero de horas: ");
                horas = Integer.parseInt(entrada.nextLine());
                System.out.println("Introduzca el numero de materiales: ");
                numMAteriales = Integer.parseInt(entrada.nextLine());
                System.out.println("Esta finalizado T o F: ");
                f = entrada.nextLine();
                if (f.compareToIgnoreCase("t") == 0) {
                    finalizado = true;
                } else {
                    finalizado = false;
                }
                System.out.println("Indique el tipo de parte 1 parte mecanico, 2 para pintura y 3 para revision ");
                parte = Integer.parseInt(entrada.nextLine());
                if (parte == 1) {
                    ParteMecanico p = new ParteMecanico();
                    p.setFinalizado(finalizado);
                    p.setHoras(horas);
                    p.setNumMateriales(numMAteriales);
                    m.aniadirParte(parte, p);

                }
                if (parte == 2) {
                    PartePintura p = new PartePintura();
                    p.setFinalizado(finalizado);
                    p.setHoras(horas);
                    p.setNumMateriales(numMAteriales);
                    m.aniadirParte(parte, p);
                }
                if (parte == 3) {
                    ParteRevision p = new ParteRevision();
                    p.setFinalizado(finalizado);
                    p.setHoras(horas);
                    p.setNumMateriales(numMAteriales);
                    m.aniadirParte(parte, p);
                }
                break;
```

La idea es que si el añadir se ejecuta correctamente salga el mensaje

Comment: Veo mucho código redundante. Deberías de simplificar y editar la pregunta, de este modo, facilitas la lectura del lector.

Comment: Que sería en tu caso que el método "se ejecute correctamente"? Como tal solo hace asignaciones y no hay lógica compleja como para que pueda fallar. Si acaso quizás deberías añadir un case default...

Comment: a ver yo tengo el metodo añadir en su respectiva clase y luego lo llamo en el main, pues si se añade correctametne en el main envio un mensaje diciendo se ha añadido correctamente por ejemplo

Answer (score 0):

Me parece estás un tanto confundido, ya que el como declares los métodos no debería ir en función de lo que te agrade mas y si de lo que planeas que hagan:

Por ejemplo:

- Declarar un método como `String` implica que su lógica interna va a retornar un valor de ese tipo de dato primitivo
- Declarar un método como `void` entonces va para un `setter` tal vez donde igualas una propiedad con un valor, pero no esperas que este método retorne o regrese nada.
- Los métodos establecidos como `void` no pueden contener dentro de su estructura la instrucción `return` por lo cual no se ajustan a lo que tu pretendes realizar

Aquí en la [documentación de Oracle](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/returnvalue.html) puedes comprobar lo antes mencionado.

Comment: No quiero qeu retorne nada si no no lo hubiera hecho void quiero comprobar que se ejecuta correctamente y enonces en el main dar un mensaje

Comment: Vuelvo a lo mismo entonces establece que retorna desde el inicio, no creo que sea posible modificar la naturaleza del método en tiempo de ejecución

Comment: no quiero cambiar la naturaleza del metodo, solo quiero saber si se ejecuta

Comment: Entonces como ya dije usa un método que no sea void del cual puedas retornar y asi te enterarás si es que ejecutó o no su lógica interna

Comment: si la logica la entiedo de sobra la cosa era ver si siendo void podria saber si se ejcuta o no correctamente